# SAP Fiori Launchpad - Dialog

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Our business is looking for a method of getting messages / notifications across to users in the Fiori launchpad (when needed, ie, pre-warning message that system will be down for maintenance on X day)

Options we have seen on the SAP ONE Support Launchpad are:
- Message Dialog popup on log in (eg. whats new)
- Button in shell bar with link to message dialog
- Button in footer with link to message dialog

The problem is after searching and searching we can't find out if these are even possible to implement / documentation on how to implement.

Does anyone have any knowledge of this or could point me in the right direction?

There is the news app that could pull in an RSS feed as an option but ideally would like an alternative solution.

[Message dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRROc.jpg)

[Shell bar drop down button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwwsC.jpg)

Comment: Notifications are not possible with Fiori Launchpad.
It's has been introduced in Fiori 2.0. See this link https://experience.sap.com/skillup/sap-fiori-2-0-the-launchpad-part-2/.
Move to Fiori 2.0 if it's feasible for you. Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

The launchpad has an extension concept using plugins. Here you can add buttons to the action menu, the header, the footer and some other selected places in the UI.
But I am not sure to what extend a SAP ONE Support Launchpad (that is actually based on the ushell) can be extended as one would need to make changes to the launchpad content.

The documentation about the API can be found [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw75/helpdata/en/56/e9328978954c77946b75c0976f221c/content.htm?frameset=/en/d5/8602924af34fc3816d44ddb6a9e911/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/bd/e12a271f0647e799b338574cda0808/plain.htm&node_id=130&show_children=false).

And the detailed API doc [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ushell.renderers.fiori2.Renderer.html).

A sample coding as plugin could look like this:

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/Component",
"sap/m/MessageBox"], function(Component, MessageBox) {

return Component.extend("my.FLP.plugin.Component", {

    init: function() {

        // 1. fiori renderer for reuse
        var renderer = sap.ushell.Container.getRenderer("fiori2");
        
        /**
         * 2.
         * Add Item to the Action Menu
         */

        renderer.addActionButton("sap.m.Button", {
            id: "testHomeButton",
            icon: "sap-icon://family-care",
            text: "Help for FLP page",
            press: function() {
                window.open("http://www.sap.com", "_blank");
            }
        }, true, false, [sap.ushell.renderers.fiori2.RendererExtensions.LaunchpadState.Home]);

        renderer.addActionButton("sap.m.Button", {
            id: "testAppButton",
            icon: "sap-icon://family-care",
            text: "Help for App page",
            press: function() {
                window.open("http://www.sap.com", "_blank");
            }
        }, true, false, [sap.ushell.renderers.fiori2.RendererExtensions.LaunchpadState.App]);

        /**
         * 3.
         * Add Item to the Footer
         */

        
        renderer.setFooter(new sap.m.Bar({
            design: sap.m.BarDesign.Footer,
            contentLeft: [new sap.m.Button({
                text: "Important Information",
                press: function() {
                    MessageBox.information("This Fiori Launchpad has been extended to improve your experience");
                }
            })]
        }));
```

Hope this help!